# VIsualStudio 2017 stuck during the build process

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, compilation, visual-studio-2017

I have solution with ~60 projects (`AzureWorkerRole`, `ASP.NET MVC`, `ConsoleApplication`, `Library`) written in `C#`. When i'm starting `build solution` and minimizing `VS2017` window build process become paused. If i will open `VS2017` window the build process starts to work.
i'm not sure, but looks like building stucks on:

> 11>------ Rebuild All started: Project:xxx.Client, Configuration: Debug Any CPU
>
> 11>  Feeds used:

after opening the window new lines become:

> 11>    C:\Users\Cat.nuget\packages\
>
> 11>    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
>
> 11>    http://ngdev.privaterepo.com/nuget/ph

Why `VisualStudio` stuck? How to avoid stucking?

Comment: Are your Nuget feeds accessible?

Comment: offcourse, when i open the window build continued, the question is why this happen when windo is minimized